# Gauss Bonnet theorem calculation for pseudosphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In an attempt to verify Gauss-Bonnet theorem for a Beltrami pseudosphere  I  calculated a simple case of the Riemann sphere. Am taking curved radius $a$ for geodesic polar co-ordinate from the smooth continuous (no abrupt jumps) circle center shown.

For simpler calculations we consider [Constant $(\kappa_g,K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162474/curvature-of-geodesic-circles-on-surface-with-constant-curvature)  circles/sphere or pseudosphere.

[image: GB thm for pseudosphere]

*Spherical cap area*

cap height= $ R(1-\cos (a/R))$

cap area =$ 2 \pi R^2 (1-\cos (a/R) )$

$$ \int K dA = 2 \pi (1-\cos (a/R) ) \tag1 $$

*Rotation in tangent plane*

$$ R_g= R \,\tan (a/R);\,\kappa_g = 1/R_g=\cot (a/R) /R $$

cap rim circumference = $ 2 \pi R \sin (a/R) $

$$ \int \kappa_g\, ds =  \cot (a/R) /R \cdot  2 \pi R \sin (a/R)= 2 \pi \cos (a/R) \tag2 $$

Adding 1) and 2)  we have

$$ \int K dA + \int \kappa_g\, ds = 2 \pi \tag3 $$

When $ a/R  = \pi/3 $ each term has equal contribution as $\pi,$ as $(\pi,\pi).$ And for a flat plane the terms are respectively $ (0, 2\pi)$. In hyperbolic situation the terms could be even like $(-\pi/2, 5 \pi/2),$ a situation I would in particular like to be able to see when solid angle or integral curvature  is depleted to negative value due to negative sign of Gauss curvature $K$.

How now do we calculate for the pseudosphere with an analytical formula or otherwise? For as far as I know it is not readily available using geodesic polar co-ordinates. Please help in its corresponding calculation.

EDIT1:

Also from [EarlierMSEQuestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162474/curvature-of-geodesic-circles-on-surface-with-constant-curvature) can we verify punctured disk constant $ K<0,\, \kappa_g, \chi=0$ as commented here by Neil Hoffman, that

$$  \boxed{ \int KdA = \int\int \kappa_g ds\quad ? }$$

Understanding equality of these fundamental *physical* quantities as GB thm components would be to me of humongous significance. I think it is just not there. Please enlighten me and correct me here.

Comment: I think you should consider the psuedosphere as a topological annulus (in this case a once punctured disk) so $chi=0$, then the two terms on the left hand side of (3) cancel. I more commonly think of this without integrating against a fixed curvature of -1. So for me this fact is just a repackaging of the following: the area of a horodisk neighborhood is equal to the length of its boundary in $H^2$.

Comment: For hyperbolic space, I suggest trying either the unit sphere of radius -1 in Minkowski space model or the Poincare disk model.

Comment: @NeilHoffman. OK. Considering disk of single punctured disk homeomorphic to a pseudosphere, $ \chi=0,\, \int{ K\,dA}= \int {\kappa_g \, ds} $ .equals what quantity of a particular chosen patch/configuration?   I like to make a concrete calculation at least in one case to verify with a geodesic polar coordinate drawn warped oval just as has been done for case of a sphere above,